# How to make a slider in django?

Tags: html, django, slider

I have a a variable, which users can input. I want them to use an ordinary slider from 50 to 100, with a step of 5. However, I can't find how I can make it in django views or in my template. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an object slider in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119351/how-to-make-an-object-slider-in-django)

Answer (score 9):

This is not a job for Django. It's a job for JavaScript. A slider isn't a standard HTML element.

Comment: Well, except if you're using [HTML5](http://learnwebtutorials.com/example/html5/slider-control.html), and your visitors are using a browser that supports it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it.